pytorch: IndexError: index out of range in self
I'm following this github code to try and run the model using my own chats. I was able to fix a few things that initially didn't work for me (regex, encoding while leading the txt file)
I'm having 764 unique tokens in my file and I get this error when I run the run.py train --update function.
Loaded existing model to continue training.
Parameters to be optimized: 4831966

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\VS Code Projects\.venv\codes\new\lad-gpt\run.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\VS Code Projects\.venv\codes\new\lad-gpt\run.py", line 15, in main
    train.model_training(args.update)
  File "E:\VS Code Projects\.venv\codes\new\lad-gpt\src\train.py", line 55, in model_training
    train_loss = estimate_loss(model, train_data)
  File "E:\VS Code Projects\.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\VS Code Projects\.venv\codes\new\lad-gpt\src\utils.py", line 23, in estimate_loss
    logits, loss = model(X, Y)
  File "E:\VS Code Projects\.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\VS Code Projects\.venv\codes\new\lad-gpt\src\model.py", line 150, in forward
    tok_emb = self.token_embedding(idx)                     # (B, T, C)
  File "E:\VS Code Projects\.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\VS Code Projects\.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\sparse.py", line 162, in forward
    return F.embedding(
  File "E:\VS Code Projects\.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2210, in embedding
    return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
IndexError: index out of range in self

what changes do I need to do to make this work?
I tried looking into the nn.embedding, vocab size etc but the code uses len(vocab) which eliminates any error with the embedding function. the embedding size is at 256 and i've tried both a higher and lower value and I still have the same error. I don't completely understand what's the error to proceed further.

It looks like you're trying to access an index out of the bounds of the embedding. Have you tried using a debugger to print the values of weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq and sparse?

I just had the same problem.
I am training an NLP with my own data.
The data I provided to the model was parsed incorrectly. Instead of tokenizing words or sentences I had tokenized the whole text and saved it as a single token.
Just check the data you are providing and you should be able to see the problem.

So the code works when the input is less. When I use a large input text file, I run into this error. Otherwise it works fine with no issues

Could you please add the specific code that is failing and maybe a sample of the data you are providing? (have to admit i'm very new to AI training but I'll try my best)

I'm pretty new to this as well. I'm just trying to replicate this https://github.com/bernhard-pfann/lad-gpt and use my own chat history. There's nothing else that I changed except for some new parameters to use utf8 encoding etc. Hope this helps!
